# Copy Content from original site to new site (multi-site)

Tags: craft3, multi-site

I have an English site with content, but now I need to create another site in French. So I'm setting up a multisite for my Craft install. I want to copy over all my English content over to my new site as a starting point, but their content will deviate in the future so I want to use the Propagation Method: Only save entries to the site they were created in. However, when I use this propagation method, all the content is gone. How do I copy over content from my original site to my new site?